# How to detect prefetching from the browser in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, prefetch

Some pages can be prefetched by the browser (see [this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-prefetch) or [that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83656/wordpress-tries-to-load-next-page-after-done-loading-current-page)). How to detect in PHP that a request is a prefetched request ?

Is there any method is not browser-specific ?

(PS: I use Apache.)

Comment: Prefetch is not widely supported. If you could detect it, whoat would you do with the information?

Comment: In fact there is both pre-rendering and prefetching! This causes me a headache as in these requests COOKIEs are sent to server but they are not updated in return, causing many session update issue for me specially since there is no way to distinguishes these requests from actual requests.

Comment: @user1864610 I have a form token that always refreshed on every page visits. This feature always invalidate the form token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a similar answer to stop FF and other browsers throwing out my server side page counts.

- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ#As_a_server_admin.2C_can_I_distinguish_prefetch_requests_from_normal_requests.3F)
- [Chrome white paper](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender)

According to the articles above, Firefox sends a header which makes it easy to detect but the Chrome white paper states that Chrome doesn't give any indication to the server. The Chrome white paper notes that external analytic solutions (scripts written in JS) will not count the prefetch hits when they use the [page visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API).

My suggestion is to write your own JS script to detect if the page is ever made visible.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to "How to detect if cookies are enabled?". But you must use client-side redirection, because prefetched page start loading after loading main page.

Directly prefetch request can by detected by header (`X-Moz: prefetch` for FF) or by passing additional param to a link.

P.S. Without cookies enabled you cannot detect it for client, only for each directory prefetch request.