# HTML/Javascript: How to distinguish real views from prerendered/prefetched pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application that works similar to an image gallery (that means it has many pages in a certain clear order and the user usually goes from one page to the next in that order) and I remember on the server the page the user has visited last. Prerendering/Prefetching is a great way to improve performance for that use-case, but it messes up my bookmarking algorithm, because the bookmark is set to the page that was loaded last by the browser and not the page that the user actually had on screen.

Is there a reliable way to distinguish real views from prefetch/prerender?

Is this done server-side (check something the browser sets while requesting the page) or client-side (by a Javascript command)?

Comment: Yes, there is. But since you show no code, we will show no answer.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea where to begin - Javascript? or check some variable that is set by the browser in PHP? I will clarify the question.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138712/how-to-detect-prefetching-from-the-browser-in-php